# note application that willsync with a android client ubuntu 14.10

Tags: android, sync, tomboy, notes, evernote

hi just installed ubuntu 14.10 and very happy with it
got everything setup nicely but disappointed again everpad or nixnote wont work
ive tried the following that might have sync function 
everpad
nixnote
both fail with authentication
tomboy 
needs webdav
i also tried springseed which looks great and syns with dropbox but no android client 
all the sync clients look like they need ubuntu one which of course has gone

ive tried nixnote 2 beta which i can do a force to intall because it wont install because of libpoppler requirements and it runs but then package manger realises it is broke and keeps removing it! 
any solutions available apart from using the evernote webclient ...

Comment: You could use [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com). Just install the Android app and use the webapp on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) - it can be used to write notes, do lists and take photos.

It has a [App for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep), which can be used offline, and  includes a widget:
 [image]

You can then access it from Ubuntu and other computer using your Google Account:
 [image]

It also has a [Google Chrome/Chromium app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki), which like the android app is usable offline, and syncs when online.

[image]